# get_serving_url question

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Hi My question is whether I've understood the usage correctly: Adding =s120 to the url will scale the image to 120 pixels and adding the parameter `size=120` will behave differently: It will only shrink images larger than 120 pixels. Is this true?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

`size=120` is something you could pass as the 2nd argument to the get_serving_url method. `=s120` would be something that you append to the URL returned by get_serving_url.

The effect is the same: larger images are scaled down, but smaller images are not scaled up.

Comment: Thanks! Important for me is that smaller images don't scale up.

Comment: Google could do a better job of making this behavior clear in the docs.